# DJI SDK startListeningForChanges not working

Tags: swiftui, dji-sdk

I want to get the update of the Compass of my P4 RTK with my Mobile SDK for iOS, but I am not getting any output in the terminal.

I am using SwiftUI on Xcode.

This is the code I am using.

```
if let locationKey = DJIFlightControllerKey(param: DJIFlightControllerParamCompassHeading) {
   DJISDKManager.keyManager()?.startListeningForChanges(on: locationKey, withListener: self, andUpdate: { (oldValue: DJIKeyedValue?, newValue: DJIKeyedValue?) in
      if (newValue != nil) {
         print("Compass: \(newValue!.doubleValue)")
                        
      }
   })
}
```

If I unterstand the code startListeningForChanges right, I should get an print output, when I rotate the drone?

Comment: In what flight mode are you?

Comment: The flight mode the drone is using, is DJIFlightModeManual.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to get the compass value by implementing `DJICompassDelegate.didUpdateSensorState`, e.g.

```swift
class CompassDelegate: DJICompassDelegate {

    var sensorValue: Float = 0.0

    ...

    func compass(_ compass: DJICompass, didUpdateSensorState state: DJICompassState) {
        if self.sensorValue != state.sensorValue
           && state.index == 0 { // depending on your drone model there might be multiple compasses as far as I understood
            self.sensorValue = state.sensorValue
        }
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your code where you have your instance of DJIFlightController you need to set an instance of this compass delegate, e.g.

```swift
myFlightController.compass?.delegate = myCompassDelegate
```